# How to prove that a matrix is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

Let $L$ be a Laplacian matrix of a strong connected and balanced directed
graph. Define
$$
L^{s}=\frac{1}{2}\left( L+L^{T}\right) .$$
Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix with
$$
D=\begin{bmatrix}
d_{1} &  &  &  \\
& d_{2} &  &  \\
&  & \ddots &  \\
&  &  & d_{n}%
\end{bmatrix},
$$
with $d_{i}\geq 0.$ There is at least one $d_{i}>0$. Clearly, this matrix is positive semi-definite. Is the matrix
$
L^{s}+D
$
positive definite or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take any nonzero $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbf{R}^n$ and let $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\dotsc ,x_n)$.

Then

$\quad \mathbf{x} L_s\mathbf{x}^t=\sum_{ij} (x_i-x_j)^2 > 0$,

where the sum is taken over the edges of the graph (edges without orientation), which shows that $L_s$ is positive definite (the graph is strongly connected). On the other hand $D$ is clearly positive semi-definite, and hence the addition of both matrices is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks for A.Schulz's answer. I got some hint from you. The matrix $L^{s}+D$ is positive definite, not just positive semi-definite. Follow A.Schulz's proof, we have
$
x\left( L^{s}+D\right) x=\sum_{ij}\left( x_{i}-x_{j}\right)
^{2}+\sum_{i}d_{i}x_{i}^{2}
$.

Suppose $d_{i}$ is positive. If $x\left( L^{s}+D\right) x=0$, then $x_{i}=0$, then the graph is strongly connected, then all $x_{j}=0$. Thus we get that $L^{s}+D$ is positive definite.

Comment: @XiangyuMeng: Thanks, I have missed the fact that the one of the $d_i$s is positive. I edited the answer.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you missed (that at least one of the $d_i$ is positive, or that all the others can be zero), but in any case $D$ is only positive semi-definite; it is definitely :-) not "clearly positive definite".

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: We cannot allow that the graph contains no edges at all since the graph is strongly connected.

Comment: @XiangyuMeng: Darn, I totally missed that. I was getting your first answer wrong, and was only looking at the restrictions of $D$. Thanks!